# Weird issue where __autoload stops working

Tags: php, autoload

I'm having the weirdest problem. I have an `__autoload` function that handles all my class including. At one point in my code, namely between `new XLSReader()` and `new CVSReader()`, the `__autoload` function just stops being used. Consequently I'm getting `class CSVReader not found` errors. This is the code where `__autoload` stops working

```
// Get general data
printf("Fetching data from \"%s\"... ", $data_file);
$csvreader = new \XLSReader($data_file, $columnsToFetch);
$data = $csvreader->getData();
print("Done.\n");

// Get IP data
print("Loading IP addresses... ");
$csvreader = new \CSVReader($ip_file, null);
$ip_data = $csvreader->getData();
print("Done.\n");
```

I know the `__autoload` function has stopped working, because I manually included the `CSVReader` class and got `not found` errors on the next class that should have been auto-loaded.

To make it clear, before the above code snippet, auto-loading is working just like it should. Also, here is the `__autoload` function

```
// Autoload
function __autoload($classname)
{
    $classname = str_replace("\\", "/", $classname);

    $path = "code/" . $classname . ".php";

    if(is_file($path))
    {
        include($path);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does file `code/CSVReader.php` exists? Keep in mind that *nix-based systems are **case sensitive**.

Comment: Echo out $classname in your __autoload() function. It seems that you have a mixup with namespaces when it comes to that CVSReader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might you be running into the murky waters of using `__autoload()` instead of `spl_autoload_register()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

It might also be a case issue, or the non-absolute file path that you're using in your autoload function.

If the latter, prepend $path with `__DIR__` (or `dirname(__FILE__)`), or whatever is needed in your setup:

```
$path = __DIR__ . $path;
```

Comment: Indeed, using `spl_autoload_register()` succeeded where `__autoload()` failed. Thanks for your answer!